# jsf dynamic change of managedbean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

How can I dynamically change managed bean of "value" attribute? For example, I have h:inputText and, depending on typed-in text, managed bean must be #{studentBean.login} or #{lecturerBean.login}. In a simplified form:

```
<h:inputText id="loginField" value="#{'nameofbean'.login}" />
```

I tried to embed another el-expression instead of 'nameofbean':

```
value="#{{userBean.specifyLogin()}.login}"
```

but it doesn't worked out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polymorphism should rather be done in the model, not in the view.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText value="#{person.login}" />
```

with

```
public interface Person {
    public void login();
}
```

and

```
public class Student implements Person {
    public void login() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Lecturer implements Person {
    public void login() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and finally in the managed bean

```
private Person person;

public String login() {
    if (isStudent) person = new Student(); // Rather use factory.
    // ...
    if (isLecturer) person = new Lecturer(); // Rather use factory.
    // ...
    person.login();
    // ...
    return "home";
}
```

Otherwise you have to change the view everytime when you add/remove a different type of `Person`. This is not right.

Comment: OK, but Student and Lecturer must have also specific field. I mean they have to implement not just Person interface but **Person<Toloko>**, for example. I specified proper getter and setter in **public interface Person<T> { public T getToloko() ...**, but in managed bean, when I want to get access to it - #{registration.person.toloko}, they see **toloko** as example of some **T** class (???) and not a Toloko. How can I solve it?

Comment: added: Person class has overriden getters and setters.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
<h:inputText id="loginField1" value="#{bean1.login}" rendered="someCondition1"/>
<h:inputText id="loginField2" value="#{bean2.login}" rendered="someCondition2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've totally forgotten about rendered attribute.