# Reuse a facelet in multiple beans

Tags: java, jsf, el, managed-bean

How do I invoke/access a property of a managed bean when the bean name is known, but is not yet constructed?

For example:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(bean).text}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(bean).values}" var="val"
        itemLabel="#{val}" itemValue="#{val}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

If there is a managed bean called testBean and in my view *bean* has the `"testBean"`value, I want the *text* or *values* property of testBean to be called.

**EDIT1**

**The context**

An object consists of a list of properties(values). One property is modified with a custom JSF editor, depending on its type.

The list of editors is determined from the object's type, and displayed in a form using `custom:include` tags. This custom tag is used to dynamically include the editors `<custom:include src="#{editor.component}">`. The *component* property points to the location of the JSF editor.

In my example some editors(rendered as select boxes) will use the same facelet(dynamicDropdown.xhtml). Every editor has a session scoped managed bean. I want to reuse the same facelet with multiple beans and to pass the name of the bean to dynamicDropdown.xhtml using the *bean* param.

`genericAccount.xhtml`

```
<p:dataTable value="#{group.editors}" var="editor">
    <p:column headerText="Key">
        <h:outputText value="#{editor.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Value">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not editor.href}">
            <h:outputText value="#{editor.component}" escape="false" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editor.href}">
            <custom:include src="#{editor.component}">
                <ui:param name="bean" value="#{editor.bean}"/>  
            <custom:include>
       </h:panelGroup>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

`#{editor.component}` refers to a dynamicDropdown.xhtml file.

`dynamicDropdown.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(bean).text}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(bean).values}" var="val"
        itemLabel="#{val}" itemValue="#{val}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>  
</ui:composition>
```

`eval` is a managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "eval")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ELEvaluator {
    ...

    public Object evaluateAsBean(String el) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Object bean = context.getELContext()
            .getELResolver().getValue(context.getELContext(), null, el);
        return bean;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your concrete question/problem? You seem to have found the solution already, but I don't see any question/problem related to it.

Comment: I get this exception for <p:selectOneMenu value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(bean).text}">: SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/editors/dynamicDropdown.xhtml @13,73 value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean('profile').text}": Property 'evaluateAsBean' not found on type com.acme.client.util.ELEvaluator

Comment: Apparently your environment doesn't support EL 2.2. What container make/version are you using? What servlet version is your `web.xml` declared to?

Comment: I am using servlet-api 2.5, PrimeFaces 3.0.M3, jsf-api and jsf-impl 2.0.4-b09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am using servlet-api 2.5*

Servlet 2.5 implies EL 2.1. Invoking methods with arguments is not supported in EL 2.1. It's introduced in EL 2.2 which implies Servlet 3.0.

If you can't upgrade to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), then you need to upgrade the EL 2.1 implementation instead. JBoss EL is an EL 2.1 compatible implementation which supports the same new features as in EL 2.2. To install it, just drop [jboss-el.jar](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and add the following context parameter to `web.xml`, assuming that you're using Mojarra:

```xml
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have passed the bean via JSF, for instance by passing bean="#{testBean}" to your view, you would access the property with value="#{cc.attrs.bean.test}"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question `<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}"/>` would print the text of the property on your screen ofcourse your managed bean should be annotated as such with @ManagedBean.

Comment: It should do the same thing as #{testBean.text}.

Comment: I am sorry but to me personally your question is very ambiguous, if you  give more precise example and/or explanation i will try to help you.

Comment: Instead of having a hardcode bean in the facelet, like#{testBean.text}, I want to pass a string representing the name of the bean. This way I will be able to pass diferent bean names and reuse the same view.

Comment: In that case your answer is here hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/6026704/1382151